# Chrome extension - response of ajax(settings).done won't display in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

Am trying to display the response data of `ajax(settings).done` in the `popup.html` of my Chrome extension. But it is not working. It displays in `console.log` though.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Malware Detector",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<body>
    <div id="resultsDisplay"></div>
    <script src="cloudmersive-validate-client.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    // api
    var settings = {
         "url": "https://api.cloudmersive.com/virus/scan/website",
         "method": "POST",
         "timeout": 0,
         "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "Apikey": "my_key_here"
         },
         "data": {
              "Url": tab.url
         }
    };
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         $("#resultsDisplay").html(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Check if the element is there `console.log($("#resultsDisplay").length)`

Comment: @jcubic It returns 1